# Heatmap with 2d smoothing using levelplot function from latticeExtra

Tags: heatmap, contour, lattice, levelplot

I have been trying to reproduce [this plot](https://r-graph-gallery.com/201-levelplot-with-latticeextra_files/figure-html/thecode-1.png) using the code from [here](https://r-graph-gallery.com/201-levelplot-with-latticeextra.html)

My last attempts got me pretty close but I can't find the appropiate way to make the graph look like I want.
In my data, z is the numerical result of a simulation carried out under x and y conditions and I want to map that relationship, like you could do simply by a scatterplot but prettier.

My df is pretty large but it has this aspect:

- x -> continous variable ranging from 120 - 300
- y -> continous variable ranging from 0.2 - 1.8
- z -> continous variable ranging from -0.0001 to 3000

This is my [First attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAmgL.jpg) generated with this code

```
levelplot(z ~ x * y, 
          data, 
          panel = panel.levelplot.points, 
          cex = 0.7,
          col.regions = rocket(25, alpha = .8, direction = -1),
          colorkey = list(at = (breaks = c(1, 20, 50, 150, 500, Inf))),
          scales = list(x=list(at = c(120, 140, 160, 180, 200, 220, 240, 260, 280, 299))),
          xlab = "x", 
          ylab = "y"
) + 
  layer_(panel.2dsmoother(..., n = 100))
```

The problem is that, while points are a fair representation of my data, the 2d layer is not. I want to specially stress the difference between <1 and >=1 so my breaks start by 1, the rest would be the scale depending on z values for different experiments (this one reaches over 3000, other just up to 30)

I have also attempted to sepparate both graphs and you can take a look at the [scatter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeOvr.jpg) and the [2dSmooth panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSUtp.jpg). Here is the code for both:

```
## Scatter
levelplot(z ~ x * y, 
          data,
          panel = panel.levelplot.points, 
          cex = 0.7,
          at = c(-Inf, 1, 30, 100, 500, Inf),   
          col.regions = rocket(25, alpha = .8, direction = -1),
          colorkey = list(
            labels = c("", "1", "30", "100", "500", "")
          ),
          scales = list(x=list(at = c(120, 140, 160, 180, 200, 220, 240, 260, 280, 299))),
          xlab = "x", 
          ylab = "y" ) 

## 2dSmooth
levelplot(z ~ x * y, 
          data,
          panel = panel.2dsmoother,
          n = 200, 
          cuts = 5,
          col.regions = rocket(25, alpha = .8, direction = -1),
          colorkey = T,
          scales = list(x=list(at = c(120, 140, 160, 180, 200, 220, 240, 260, 280, 299))),
          xlab = "x", 
          ylab = "y"
)
```

Note I am having troubles with CUT and AT.
When I pass the AT argument to my 2dSmooth graph, the result is [absurd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTAIK.jpg) and I have no idea why.

However, the CUT result from the 2dSmooth plot are addequate, the problem is that I cannot label them as I don't know the limits the function has taken. If there would be a way of correctly labelling that graph, that would be it. Otherwise, I need to combine both.

¿Any idea where I am messing up?
¿Any possibility of having my 2dsmooth graph done with other libraries? So far I haven't found anything similar to levelplot() with panel.2dsmoother

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems very specific to your data, so it's difficult to answer without having access to it. But generally speaking,

- I'm a bit surprised that you are getting a different set of cut points with your 2dSmooth graph, because when you don't specify `at`, the default values should only depend on the data (which remain unchanged) and not on the panel function. I'm not sure what's happening.
- `panel.2dsmoother()` basically just fits a regression surface to your data, by default using `loess()`. If your goal is to remove the influence of "outliers" by tuning your `at` values to the fitted surface instead of the data, you would need to do that externally. You can mimic the code of `panel.2dsmoother()` to do this, e.g.,

```r
n <-  100
mod <- loess(z ~ x * y, data)
xseq <- seq(120, 300, length = n)
yseq <- seq(0.2, 1.8, length = n)
grid <- expand.grid(x = xseq, y = yseq)
fit <- predict(mod, grid)
```

You could now visualize this surface using a standard `levelplot()` call using

```r
(p <- levelplot(fit ~ x + y, grid))
```

and the corresponding `at` values should be roughly

```r
do.breaks(range(fit), 5)
```

You can get the exact values using

```
trellis.panelArgs(p, 1)$at
```